# move camera position y when collided on trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine

If my character collided in an Object, I want my camera position y to move down a bit. I have tried to program it like this :

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider other)
{
                float x = Camera.main.transform.position.x;
                float y = Camera.main.transform.position.y;
                Vector3 origPOS = new Vector3(x, (Mathf.Lerp(y, -3, 3 * Time.deltaTime)), 0);
                Camera.main.transform.position = origPOS;
}
```

but it does not behave like I want to. Can you guys help me?

This is the image of the original position of the Camera:
[image]

This the desired position of my Camera when my character collided in an object and perform the function that will move my Camera:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this line of code is called only once (When your character collided) and end before reaching desired destination

`Vector3 origPOS = new Vector3(x, (Mathf.Lerp(y, -3, 3 * Time.deltaTime)), 0)`

you have to lerp continuously until you reach desired position like this

```
float t = 0.0f;
while ( t<1.0f )
{
    float x = Camera.main.transform.position.x;
    float y = Camera.main.transform.position.y;
    t += Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 origPOS = new Vector3(x, (Mathf.Lerp(y, -3, 3 * Time.deltaTime),t), 0)
    Camera.main.transform.position = origPOS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) when colliding to move your camera :

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider other)
{
    StartCoroutine(MoveCamera());
}

IEnumerator MoveCamera()
{
    float t = 0.0f;

    Vector3 originPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
    Vector3 endPosition = new Vector3(originPosition.x, originPosition.y - 3, originPosition.z);

    while ( t < 1.0f )
    {
        Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPosition, endPosition, t);
        t += Time.deltaTime * CameraSpeed; // CameraSpeed is the speed of your camera.

        yield return null; // Don't forget this line !
    }
}
```